# Two different types of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'm trying to sort my array of Star Wars episodes by episode ID. I faced a strange problem. I have **first** array (marked as "1" on screenshot) and **second** array (marked as "2" on screenshot).

The **first** one is just data pasted into code:

```
const test = [
        { title: 'The Empire Strikes Back', episode_id: 5 },
        { title: 'A New Hope', episode_id: 4 },
        { title: 'Attack of the Clones', episode_id: 2 },
        { title: 'Return of the Jedi', episode_id: 6 },
        { title: 'The Phantom Menace', episode_id: 1 },
        { title: 'Revenge of the Sith', episode_id: 3 },
      ];
```

The **second** one is function which takes an array of endpoints (filmsArray) and then gets the specific title and episode_id from all endpoints, and then pushing it into array as object and returns that array.

```
const handleGetFilms = (filmsArray) => {
    const titlesArray = [];
    filmsArray.forEach(async (film) => {
      const {
        data: { title, episode_id },
      } = await axios.get(film);
      titlesArray.push({ title, episode_id });
    });
    return titlesArray;
  };
```

As you can see on the screenshot - sorting for the **first** array (which is just data pasted into code) works well, but sorting for the **second** (which is dynamic data) is not working at all. Because of that I have two questions:

1. Why this sorting isn't working for the **second** array? (I'm using the same array.sort function for both of these arrays)
2. Why there's a difference between console.log for those two arrays? Shouldn't they be the same?(Marked as green on the screenshot)

EDIT:
I'm adding the sorting code:

```
arrayName.sort((a, b) => a.episode_id - b.episode_id)
```

[image]

Comment: The console prints a static preview of the object at the time of execution of `console.log`. If you later click onto the object/array in the console, the reference to that array is loaded and the data is refreshed.

Comment: can you post the code snippet of sorting logic?

Comment: `filmsArray.forEach(async` doesn't work as you expect. It fires your promises and then moves on without waiting for them to complete. You need a `for` loop here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @Ravikumar I added the sorting logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change foreach with normal for loop or other options. forEach loop doesn't support for async await because forEach expects a synchronous function only.